# LNK 1120 Fatal error in Dark GDK 2d game

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008, lnk2001, darkbasic

I recently started coding and i've wrote like 2 programs before the error showed up. I wanted to begin a new project when this error showed up:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: XYZ, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup
1>Debug\XYZ.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Cieslik Michal\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\XYZ\XYZ\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>XYZ - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I cant acces the Project>Properties......  because it doesn't show up on the DarkGDK - 2D Game.

When I try running the code that comes from the template, it runs without problems, but when I try to run anything ( even a blank page or only #include "DarkGDK.h") it still gives me an error above.

I am really desperate, because it worked half an hour ago but now it stopped working completely. (I have wrote a tag darkbasic because its the closest thing to darkGDK I saw there)

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: It seems like  chose the right template, because I used it for 2 other programs and it worked (it was in the same day).

Comment: You've chosen the wrong project type.

Comment: No I haven't. I've chosen the one that I have always been choosing.

Comment: I haven't written any code and the same message appeared. This is the same template ai was always using